# Please check my semantic deduction theorem proof

Tags: logic

**I) (1)** Let's assume that $X,\alpha\models \beta$. **(2)** Let's assume that $   X\not\models\alpha\Rightarrow\beta$.

From (2) we have that there exists such $v$ that $v(X)\subseteq\{1\}$ and $v(\alpha\Rightarrow\beta)=0$. So we have that there exists such $v$ that $v(X)\subseteq\{1\}$ and $v(\alpha)=1$ and $v(\beta)=0$. This means that there exists such $v$ that  $v(X,\alpha)\subseteq\{1\}$ and $v(\beta)=0$

From (1) we have that for any $v$: if $v(X,\alpha)\subseteq \{1\}$, then $v(\beta)=1$. So we can use from (2) the assumption that "there exists $v$ such that $v(X,\alpha)\subseteq\{1\}$ Adding this to (1) we get that "for any $v$: $v(\beta)=1$". And this is contradiction to "there exists $v$ such that $v(\beta)=0$".

**(II) (1)** Let's assume that $\models\alpha\Rightarrow\beta$. **(2)** Let's assume that $X, \alpha\not\models \beta$.

From (2) we have that there exists $v$ such that $v(X,\alpha)\subseteq\{1\}$ and $v(\beta)=0$. So we have that there exists $v$ such that $v(X)\subseteq\{1\}$ and $v(\alpha)=1$ and $v(\beta)=0$

From (1) we have that for any $v$: $v(\alpha)=0$ or $v(\beta)=1$.

Let's assume that "for any $v$: $v(\alpha)=0$". This contradicts "there exists $v$ such that $v(\alpha)=1$.

Let's assume that "for any $v$: $v(\beta)=1$". This contradicts "there exists $v$ such that $v(\beta)=0$.

**The end of proof.**

I will also add an **extra question.** Can we say, like for implication, that $X,\alpha \models \beta$ when "for any $v$: $v(X,\alpha)\subseteq \{1\}$ or $v(\beta)=0$"?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: typos

Comment: Extra question $X, \alpha \vDash \beta$ means $X \cup \{ \alpha \} \vDash \beta$, i.e. that for every $v$, if $v(X, \alpha) \subseteq \{ 1 \}$, then also $v(\beta)=1$.